# cakephp find method not working

Tags: cakephp

I know this is very silly question but here I am not getting any error.

Bellow query working fine

```
$data=$this->Test->query('SELECT * FROM tests where report_id=85');
```

But same query in find method are not working

```
$condition=array('Test.report_id'=>85);
$data=$this->Test->find('all',array('condition'=>$condition));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**find** statement in cakephp  should be

```
$condition=array('Test.report_id'=>85);
$data = $this->Test->find('all',array('conditions'=>$condition));
```

Comment: OPS !! I missed  "s". Thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cakephp find statement error in 'codintion' 
You should try this
$data=$this->Test->find('all',
  array('conditions'=>
  array('Test.report_id'=>85)
 )
);
```

> please replace condition to conditions

Comment: This makes things `Complicated` if you use all arrays in one place. You should specify the array values in variables and then assign it in `find` method. Syntax `$data=$this->Test->find('all',
  array('conditions'=>
  array('Test.report_id'=>85)
 )`

can make things complicated if there are 6,7 or more parameter to pass to `find` method , so please use variables and use it in syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You made Typo.And lets understand why 's' is used.

There can be 100 conditions in an array , Not only one , so its `conditions`

```
$conditions=array('Test.report_id'=>85);
$data = $this->Test->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions));
```

And another thing -> Always use `$conditions` as variable naming convention because you never know there are 1,2, or 1000 conditions .